# How to prevent event for primeng dropdown?

Tags: angular, primeng

I would like to know how can i **prevent the event** for the primeng dropdown.

Kindly note: I do not want to disable the options.

Comment: can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @AakashGarg When I Select any value from the options i would like to compare that value. Ff that value exists then event should not occur.

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look to [the documentation](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown)

**On your template**

```
<p-dropdown [options]="yourDropdownOptions" [(ngModel)]="dropdownSelectedValue" (onChange)="onChange($event)"></p-dropdown>
```

**On the .ts you can compare the selected value with whatever logic you want**

```
onChange(event) {
    console.log(event.value); 
}
```